# How to initialize and make use of a static class?

Tags: c#, static, initialization, static-class

I have a static class which is used to access a static concurrentdictionary:

```
public static class LinkProvider
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<String, APNLink.Link> deviceLinks;
    static LinkProvider()
    {
        int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        int concurrencyLevel = numProcs * 2;
        deviceLinks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, APNLink.Link>(concurrencyLevel, 64);
    }


    public APNLink.Link getDeviceLink(string deviceId, string userId)
    {
        var result = deviceLinks.First(x => x.Key == deviceId).Value;
        if (result == null)
        {      
           var link = new APNLink.Link(username, accountCode, new APNLink.DeviceType());
           deviceLinks.TryAdd(deviceId, link);
           return link;

        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }


    public bool RemoveLink(string deviceId)
    {
        //not implmented
        return false;
    }
}
```

how can I make use of this class in my controller in an asp.net

Ie I want to go:

```
LinkProvider provider;
APNLink.Link tmpLink = provider.getDeviceLink(id, User.Identity.Name);
//use my link
```

Back ground. The dictionary is used to save a link object between states / requests in a asp.net web api program.  So when the service needs to use the link, it asks the linkprovider to find a link for it and if there isn't one it must create one. So I need the dictionary object to the same instance in all my http requests.

Comment: If you are doing a static class, everything should be static. Have a private `bool` to flag if initialized, and take care of that at the beginning of `getDeviceLink`.

Comment: Do I really need a static class in my scenario then? Can I not just make the dictionary static?

Comment: Do you *need* and instance of `LinkProvider` to work with the dictionary if the dictionary is static? Maybe. Depends on what else it is doing with *non static* data. But if not, a static class may be entirely appropriate.

Comment: In other words, if the dictionary is static and all of the methods only work with that dictionary and *don't* need any other data, then a static class is probably most appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I need the dictionary object to the same instance in all my http
>   requests

Then use a `static` class, and make every method `static` too, so you could call it using the following syntax:

```
APNLink.Link tmpLink = LinkProvider.getDeviceLink(id, User.Identity.Name);
```

That being said, you should be aware that in-memory static variables in an ASP.Net application are not always *safe to use*, because your application isn't stateless and in case the application pool is recycled, your dictionary will be re-instantiated.

Comment: Can I not initialize the class in my Startup class that asp.net provides where you normally add custom filters and routes? How does the initializing of the static class then work?

Comment: @Zapnologica Well it's a bit hard to tell _exactly when_ the static constructor will be called, but in any case it will be called before any static method/member of the class is used in your code (for a static class, and before any instance method/member for a non-static class).

Comment: So is my constructor fine in the example app? But will my constructor not be called every time I use the link provider

Comment: @Zapnologica Yes, your constructor is fine, and it will be called only once. But getDeviceLink should be static.